# How to thank colleagues helped over the Christmas weekend on very big prod issue?

Tags: software-industry, colleagues, offices

Office location: CA, USA

Issue started on Last Friday and many had already gone for vacation. Issue started in production due to my code, committed years back. Many colleagues joined the bridge and helped a lot. As production deployment had to be done, it was across different teams too. It had top management also. I would like to thank them. I considered lunch/drink, but I can't afford.

Cards + chocolate (or any other good option also fine) @desk - I am fine with this idea, have seen people doing it. It may be opt as new year is on the way. 
But what shall I write in there? Any decent, very good thank you note? Also shall I add sorry also in there? Which will be the best?

Comment: Shake hands, "Seriously, thanks for all your help this weekend. I really appreciate it."

Comment: Whats with the random downvotes without comment?

Comment: Just because you committed the code "years ago" doesn't mean that you should feel like you're the lone person responsible for this happening. That's several years of testing that missed the problem in that code and probably a half-dozen or more other people who overlooked it too. The few programmers who have written anything approaching perfect non-trivial code are named [Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_reward_check) or built the [Space Shuttle](http://www.fastcompany.com/28121/they-write-right-stuff)

Comment: Given Alroc's comment, if you still feel obliged, write an email.

Comment: Chocolate and a "thank you" card would be as far as I'd go - and even then it might be overkill. If everyone who ever committed code with a bug in it brought in chocolate, we'd all be overweight. (Oh, we *are* all overweight. Huh. Just goes to show... :-). First, don't feel bad - any developer with any length of experience has done this. You fix it, you say "thanks", you move forward. Sometimes, just on a whim, I bring in pastry or something similar. Kind of covers me for this kind of "aw, sh*t!" moment. So...chocolate, pastry, brownies...whatever. :-)

Comment: I believe that the company has benefitted from your combined efforts, hence it's up to the company management to show its appreciation of those endeavours. The ball is squarely in management's court  and your efforts should be restricted to suggesting to your boss that a practical demonstration of that appreciation would be in order. From their viewpoint, it will also build morale and make personnel happier to repeat the effort in the inevitable future cases of similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever shout about issues that came up because of something you did which had a negative impact on system.

You may want to act nice to let everyone know but then you going to degrade your performance.

It's a workplace - get over it. They helped you, you help them when they are in trouble that's how you balance such matters... Not by buying people gifts..

Answer (score 18):

Send a thank you email to each person, and cc their boss as well.  Let the leadership know how much you appreciate their help, because that is something that can translate to raises.  Bosses need to know when their people go above and beyond.

Comment: Taking the group out for lunch as well would be a nice gesture. I don't know anyone who dislikes free food.

Comment: True, but the OP specifically mentioned that lunch was out of his budget.

Comment: Expressing your gratitude in person would also go a long way -- *in addition to* the emails, taking the time and effort to visit each participating colleague at their desk and personally thank them with a smile and a handshake underlines the sincerity of your gratitude (and has no budgetary requirement!).

Comment: +1000 for copying their boss on the thanks, or sending thanks to their boss with copy to them.  Going beyond requirements to help the company should always help their annual review scores ... at least, if management is sane.

Answer (score 6):

There are two basic goals you should have in your thanking your peers here.

**Getting them the recognition they want/deserve**

While by all means it's "their job" to step in when things go to hell, even on holidays, it's still something they should get an extra nod for. Why things happened isn't important here, only that there was a failure and people stepped up and fixed it.

For me, I would take the time to write up a nice email. Ideally you want this email to reach the respective people and their managers. You may want to make sure it's okay to contact their managers through your manager. The email should be *very* brief. Simply pointing out who you'd like to thank, that there was an outage and despite being on vacation people stepped up to see it fixed.

**Expressing your gratitude**

Your code blew up in production, it may have been a mistake, or could have been just what was right then was wrong now, regardless these people could have just ignored the issue and left it as "your problem".

They didn't, they rolled up their sleeves and helped you out. Again arguable that's "their job" but again they could have just not answered the phone, or just said "sorry man, I'm no where near a computer to help" (or other excuse)

So you feel both thankful and guilty they had to work during their vacation. You should contact them as individually as practical to give them a personal thank you. If we're talking a dozen or so people contacting them individually would be best, if we're talking like fifty you're probably better off thanking them based on team, etc.

I wouldn't apologize per se, we all make mistakes, but do make a point to thank them for helping you out with the issue despite being on vacation and that you truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I would not go about it as a I messed up and these people helped bail me out.
I don't think you should buy gifts out of your pocket.

I would couch it as a report:

Over the holiday we experienced a critical bug X in production.
The bug originated in Y.
The fix was Z.
Members that contributed include a,b,c,  ...
Sorry if I missed anyone
Thank you all for your help